# Compiler error when trying to add constant float3x3 to shader file

Tags: ios, c++11, metal

I am trying to add this code to my Metal language file:

```
constant float3x3 rgb2xyz(
                      float3(0.412453f, 0.212671f, 0.019334f),
                      float3(0.357580f, 0.715160f, 0.119193f),
                      float3(0.180423f, 0.072169f, 0.950227f)
                      );
```

or this

```
constant float3x3 rgb2xyz = float3x3(
                      float3(0.412453f, 0.212671f, 0.019334f),
                      float3(0.357580f, 0.715160f, 0.119193f),
                      float3(0.180423f, 0.072169f, 0.950227f)
                      );
```

The metal compiler gives me the following error:

```
No matching constructor for initialization of 'const constant float3x3' (aka 'const constant matrix<float, 3, 3>')
```

However if I do

```
typedef struct {
    float3x3 matrix;
    float3 offset;
    float zoom;
} Conversion;

constant Conversion colorConversion = {
    .matrix = float3x3(
        float3 ( 1.164f,  1.164f, 1.164f ),
        float3 ( 0.000f, -0.392f, 2.017f ),
        float3 ( 1.596f, -0.813f, 0.000f )
    ),
    .offset = float3 ( -(16.0f/255.0f), -0.5f, -0.5f )
};
```

I don't get any compile error.

Any ideas what is going wrong? It also works without problems with vector types:

```
constant float3 bgr2xyzCol1(0.357580f, 0.715160f, 0.119193f);
```

How would be a good way to define a constant matrix directly in the code?

Comment: I'm attempting this workaround of defining a struct to hold the float3x3 and such, but that's resulting in a linker error:
"error: cannot have global constructors (llvm.global_ctors) in DepthColoringFilter".
Are you still able to compile and link that?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass it in as a constant reference, see WWDC session 604.

e.g. see `matrices` here, `TransformMatrices` is a custom data structure in this case

```
vertex VertexOutput my_vertex(const global float3* position_data [[ buffer(0) ]], const global  float3* normal_data [[ buffer(1) ]], constant TransformMatrices& matrices [[ buffer(2) ]], uint vid [[ vertex_id ]])
{
VertexOutput out;     
float3 n_d = normal_data[vid];     
float3 transformed_normal = matrices.normal_matrix * n_d; 
float4 p_d = float4(position_data[vid], 1.0f);      out.position = * p_d;
float4 eye_vector = * p_d;     
...     
return out;     
}
```

Comment: This is definitely a work around and could also be found in some of the examples. However it is kind of awkward to do using swift on the other side. It also doesn't explain why it works for some datatypes and doesn't work for some other.